# Understanding Keycloak Adapter (Spring-Security & Spring Boot) session requirement

Tags: spring-security, csrf, keycloak, websecurity

For a software in active development we are using Spring Boot (with Spring Security) and the Keycloak Adapter.

The goal is to:

- require valid authentication for all endpoints except those annotated with `@Public` (see the code snippet) (this works)
- the authentication must be via OAuth - the client gets a token directly from Keycloak and the Spring Security + Keycloak adapter make sure it is valid
- optionally, Basic Auth is also supported (the Keycloak adapter can be configured to perform a login and make it appear like a regular token auth for the rest of the code) (this works as well)

Everything is working fine as it stands, but I have some problems understanding a few details:

- The `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` enables `CSRF` protection. I think this is only done so it can register its own Matcher to allow requests from Keycloak
- It enables session management and requires some according beans
- Even though requests are made with token authentication, a `JSESSIONID` cookie is returned

According to my understanding:

- sessions should not be needed since stateless token authentication is used (so why is the `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` enabling it). Is this only for the `BASIC Auth` part?
- since sessions are enabled, `CSRF` protection is indeed needed - but I don't want the sessions in the first place and then the API would not need `CSRF` protection, right?
- even if I set `http.sessionManagement().disable()` after the `super.configure(http)` call the `JSESSIONID` cookie is set (so where is this coming from?)

As stated in the code snippet, `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` is not set to the null once since we use the `Authorization` part of Keycloak and the application is a `Service Account Manager` (thus managing those resource records).

Would be great if someone can clear things up. Thanks in advance!

```java
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new PublicHandlerMethodMatcher(requestMappingHandlerMapping))
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~ Keycloak ~~~~~~~~~~

    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    @Bean protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    /**
     * {@link NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy} is not used since we initiate logins
     * from our application and this would not be possible with {@code bearer-only}
     * clients (for which the null strategy is recommended). 
     */
    @Override
    @Bean protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    /**
     * HTTP session {@link ApplicationEvent} publisher needed for the
     * {@link SessionRegistryImpl} of {@link #sessionAuthenticationStrategy()}
     * to work properly.
     */
    @Bean public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean public KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider() {
        return super.keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may fall into excessive JWT token usage. Look at this article for example https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/. Especially look at the references at the end of the article about JWT as a session token.

For your web-application UI you are using sessions in most of the cases. It doesn't matter what type of token is used for authentication. Keycloak does everything correctly - it gives back httpOnly secure cookie for session management and tracks user status at backend. For better understanding of how it works you may look at the example code here: [examples](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-springboot)

For better separation of stateless backend (micro-)services and user UI session keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter) suggest to use 2 different authentication stratagies: `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` for sessions and `NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy` for bearer-only services